# Alias for locale or add new locale

Tags: locale

I developed a project on a Debian, but now I've installed an Ubuntu server, and the development of our projects moved to this new server.

Debian will be the production server.

When I am using gettext, the locale code on debian is `en_US` while on ubuntu there is no such code like this, but `en_US.utf8`.

I have no admin rights on debian, only ftp, and a very restricted ssh, so I can play only with ubuntu server.

I want to unify language codes on all environments, so it should be `en_US`.

How can I install this to ubuntu, or make an alias from `en_US.utf8 -> en_US`?

I've tried:

```
apt-get install language-pack-en language-pack-en-base
```

it does not helps. I also need to do this for othere languages too, like `de_DE`.

```
root@mydev:/usr/share/locales# locale -a
C
C.UTF-8
...
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8 <!-- need en_US only
en_ZA.utf8
...
POSIX
```

Comment: Have you tried `/etc/locale.alias` you should be able to achieve this: `en_US            en_US.utf8`

Comment: @George no, I am not so familiar to linux. I try it, and tell you what was the result.

Comment: Yes, it seems it works. First it has not worked, I did not understand why, but I thought, I need to restart apache and yes, after that is ok! Thank you, add it as an answer if you want me to accept it.

Comment: Great glad it worked, just added an answer :)...

Comment: Doing so will make `en_US` enable UTF-8 encoding, which in itself is good on Ubuntu. Since also Debian uses glibc, where `en_US` normally enables latin1 encoding, it's possible that you will encounter encoding problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create *aliases* using the `/etc/locale.alias`, you should be able to achieve this:

```
en_US     en_US.utf8
```

Source:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man5/locale.alias.5.html

Comment: Doing so will make `en_US` enable UTF-8 encoding, which in itself is good on Ubuntu. Since also Debian uses glibc, where `en_US` normally enables latin1 encoding, it's possible that the OP will encounter encoding problems.